# synctex problem with -output-directory in TeXLive

Tags: texlive, texworks, forward-inverse-search

I am currently using Windows 7, TeXLive2011, and TeXworks 0.4.3.

I want to put all temporary files in `tmp` directory located in the same working directory as the `.tex` file. But, I want the final `.pdf` file in the same directory as the `.tex` file, not in `tmp` directory.

I did the following:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -output-directory=tmp foo.tex
```

It put all temporary files in `tmp` directory, but also `foo.pdf`. So, I created a batch file to copy `foo.pdf` from `tmp`directory to the working directory.

```
:: %1 = tex file basename (without extension)
:: %2 = working directory

:: remove quotes in the basename tossed by TeXworks
for /f "useback tokens=*" %%a in ('%1') do set basename=%%~a
:: remove spaces in the basename tossed by TeXworks
set basename=%basename: =%

:: change / to \ in the directory name tossed by TeXworks
set dirname=%2
set dirname=%dirname:/=\%

:: create tmp directory if not exist
IF NOT EXIST %dirname%\tmp mkdir %dirname%\tmp

pdflatex -synctex=1 -output-directory=tmp %basename%.tex

:: open pdf in tmp so that synctex works in TeXworks
texworks %dirname%\tmp\%basename%.pdf

copy %dirname%\tmp\%basename%.pdf %dirname%\%basename%.pdf
```

But I have to open `foo.pdf` in `tmp` to make the forward/inverse search work in TeXworks. This works good enough to me, except one thing.

After executing the above batch file, TeXworks opens two windows: one for `foo.tex`, one for `tmp\foo.pdf`. Inverse search from `tmp\foo.pdf` to `foo.tex` works good, but if I do `Ctrl+click` in `foo.tex`, it opens `foo.pdf`, but synchronizes with `tmp\foo.pdf`. Of course, `foo.tex` does not synchronize with `foo.pdf`, because sync file is written for `tmp\foo.pdf`.

If I do not copy `tmp\foo.pdf` to `foo.pdf` in the original working directory, it works well, because there is no `foo.pdf` that TeXworks can open.

Would there be any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `-aux_directory=tmp` option instead of `-output-directory=tmp`.

This will use the `tmp` directory for the auxillary files, and leave your PDF in the source directory so you don't need to move it.  There is still the `.synctex` that gets created in the source directory. In my tests, I was able to remove that and still get the `synctex` features to work so could change your script to delete that file too.

Comment: `-aux-directory=tmp` seems work only with MikTeX. Unfortunately I use TeXlive.

Answer (score 0):

I always copy the `.synctex` (or `.synctex.gz`) file together with the PDF. This is everything that is required for SyncTeX to work, but it must be in the same directory as the PDF file.

See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87841/8057) to a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87816/is-there-a-way-to-configure-pdflatex-to-make-all-but-the-tex-and-pdf-files-hid).