# Building LaTeX files by one command

Tags: compiling, automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation)

Is there a single command which would run bibtex, makeglossary (pdflatex x N ...) etc. automatically?

I could create Makefile but it seems like overkill - is there a command for it? (LuaTeX support would be a plus).

Comment: `latexmk` can probably do all that, it is a Perl script for fully automated typesetting, and is included in both TeX Live and MikTeX. Or you could check out `arara` (search this site for some examples).

Comment: There's an answer about arara on the proposed duplicate (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77879/86).  It has the distinct advantage that the maintainer is nearly always available in the chat here (and is an all-round Good Bloke - not that the maintainers of the other methods aren't, of course).

Comment: All: please give Maciej a chance to come back and comment before voting to close as a dupe!

Comment: You can insert `bibtex`, `makeglossary`, etc, to the first code snipppet in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88805/19356). I am assuming that you are using Windows OS.

Comment: @JosephWright Whoops!  (Though I think this is fairly clear cut).  Maciej: if the linked question does *not* answer your question then please edit this question to clarify what you're looking for, then flag it for reopening and it will be reopened.

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks. I haven't found it while searching on stackexchange.