# Command line *before* \documentclass & relation with output-directory

Tags: editors, kile, output, terminal-output

This question has to do with changing the output directory on a file I am trying to compile (using Kile, though I hope the solution isn't editor-specific).  If I type

```
pdflatex -output-directory DIRECTORY file.tex
```

in a terminal window, then pdflatex is run on "file.tex", and the output (i.e., .pdf/.out/.aux files) appears in the specified directory "DIRECTORY".

My question is this: Can I include something in "file.tex" *before* the appearance of \documentclass so that the following occurs:

- I open "file.tex" using my editor (in this case, Kile).
- I hit the "pdflatex" latex button in my editor, and
- pdflatex is run on "file.tex", and the output is directed to
  "DIRECTORY"

In other words, this question is about how to amend a latex file so that the "terminal functionality" that I am able to achieve persists when using my latex editor.  At one point, someone showed me how to do something like this (it involved adding "%%!" or something similar, followed by some terminal commands), but I can't remember it now.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [arara](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) can do with `% comment lines` rules/directives see [How can I save auxiliary-files into an other folder with arara?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127298/15717) and it's Linked Q's. with [latexmk](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) see [Specify -output-directory when using latexmk](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11710/15717)