# Is there a way to organize TeX by-product files?

Tags: auxiliary-files

I rarely need the ancillary files TeX produces when compiling a document (`.aux, .log, .out, .synctex.gz`). In fact, I've only ever had to read the `.log`, and that's only a few times. Is there a way to write them to a separate directory, so that my working directory only contains `.tex` and `.pdf` files?

Comment: `pdflatex -output-directory=<folder> myfile` should do the job. I think there's a question that addresses this somewhere... it's probably worth creating a little clean up script that you can run to get rid of the 'cruft'

Comment: Perhaps you don't need those auxiliary files, but the compiler does provisionally.

Comment: Yeah, that's my concern. I don't want to delete them outright; I just don't want them cluttering up my working directory.

Comment: In my experience moving these just creates problems, if you tell latex to put them somewhere else, you then need to tell latex and all auxiliary programs where they are, and that is a frequent source of errors and questions on sites like this. It writes those files because they are _needed_ by something.

Comment: May also be useful: [Is there a way to configure pdflatex to make all but the .tex and .pdf files hidden files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87818)