# (pdf-) tex maintainers and suggestions

Tags: tex-core

in thinking about ' [Is there a way to configure pdflatex to make all but the .tex and .pdf files hidden files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87816/is-there-a-way-to-configure-pdflatex-to-make-all-but-the-tex-and-pdf-files-hid/87818#87818) ', and a suggestion for an option like --dotclutter :

who is in charge of TeX and adding command-line features these days?  TUG?  a particular individual or group of individuals?

what is a nice way to suggest small changes?

Comment: Those requests should be sent to the current maintainer of the program.

Comment: moving aux files is not a "small change" it's very disruptive as it would require changes in every program that needs to input them, latex, bibtex, makeindex, etc

Comment: hi david---doesn't the code already (more or less) exist to facilitate --output-directory ?  the only change would be not to add '/' to it by default.

Comment: @ivoWelch `--output-directory` may exist, but it often causes problems with bibliographies, index, etc. as shown by the large number of questions we have about that.

Comment: by the "question" metric, we can delete tikz and latex, too ;-).  `--output-directory` creates more questions, because other programs then need to know the directory, too.  `--output-dotfiles` would have essentially only one additional hard-coded and easily guessable destination.  but I get the point: better save my time and not ask.

Comment: TeX Live's security restrictions might have a problem with that. If `openin_any` or `openout_any` is set to `r` or `p` then read or write access to dot files is forbidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those requests, as you suggest in your title, should be send to the maintainers.
For example, for pdftex

```
pdftex --help
```

will give you a help page ending with

```
Email bug reports to pdftex@tug.org
```

Each program has it own maintainers, you should check them separately. If you don't use command line, maintainers should be found at CTAN. Although I'm not 100% sure, package maintainer can be someone else.