# TeXwork and --output-directory

Tags: texworks

When I use `xelatex.exe --output-directory=./tmp` TeXwork PDF preview will not work. Is there any solution?

Comment: Please see: [synctex problem with -output-directory in TeXLive](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31753/synctex-problem-with-output-directory-in-texlive)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer here is 'no', as TeXworks expects to find the PDF file in the same directory as the `.tex` file when doing a typesetting run. The only obvious work-around would be to create a short script as a wrapper around XeLaTeX, which would copy the PDF from the output directory to the 'current' one after the `xelatex` run, leaving all of the other files out of the way. You'd then use the script in place of the `xelatex` binary when setting up the typesetting entry.

Comment: Thanks, I hope we see a config for pdf path in future TeXworks releases.

Comment: @PHPst Well yes, would answer this answer some other questions: have you made a feature request?

Comment: No, Where can I make a NFR?

Comment: @PHPst Look at http://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues and http://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/entry

Comment: @Thanks again. I wonder that they live in Google Code yet!

Comment: After 10 years no solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if applicable on Windows, but on Linux I can create a symlink from the source directory to the build directory. This fixes the TeXworks preview.

```
cd <source directory>
ln -s build/<output>.pdf <output>.pdf
```